# mysql - get highest value from virtual column

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(number_option, 'Issue ', '') AS new_number_option FROM
jgl_article WHERE status = 1 AND topic = 'Current Issues' ORDER BY id ASC
```

new_number_option Column returns :

```
1

1

1

2

2

3

3
```

I want to get the highest value from new_number_option column. Here 3 is the highest value. So, I want to get the records which contains highest value. I tried HAVING MAX(new_number_option) in above query. But, it won't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `CAST` because your column type is `string`

```
CAST(new_number_option as SIGNED)
```

use

```
MAX( CAST(REPLACE(number_option, 'Issue ', '') AS UNSIGNED) )
```

Comment: it returns first row only. It doesn't returns the rows which contains highest value

Comment: SELECT *, 
  MAX( CAST(REPLACE(number_option, 'Issue ', '') AS UNSIGNED) ) AS new_number_option FROM
jgl_article 
WHERE status = 1 AND topic = 'Current Issues'

Comment: try this query @Beginner

Comment: tried this also. won't work. I want to get all the records which contains new_number_option = MAX(new_number_option)

Comment: SELECT * from jgl_article WHERE 
REPLACE(number_option, 'Issue ', '') in (SELECT 
MAX( CAST(REPLACE(number_option, 'Issue ', '') AS UNSIGNED) ) 
jgl_article WHERE status = 1 AND topic = 'Current Issues')

Comment: try this query @Beginner

Comment: SELECT * from jgl_article WHERE 
REPLACE(number_option, 'Issue ', '') in (SELECT 
MAX(CAST(REPLACE(number_option, 'Issue ', '') AS UNSIGNED) 
jgl_article WHERE status = 1 AND topic = 'Current Issues')

Comment: sorry please try this query

Comment: SELECT * from jgl_article WHERE 
REPLACE(number_option, 'Issue ', '') in (SELECT 
MAX(CAST(REPLACE(number_option, 'Issue ', '') AS UNSIGNED)) 
from jgl_article WHERE status = 1 AND topic = 'Current Issues')

Comment: it works. I also tried one query it works too
SELECT JA.*
  FROM
jgl_article JA INNER JOIN
     (SELECT RIGHT(number_option,1) as trimmed_col FROM jgl_article ORDER BY trimmed_col DESC LIMIT 1) T
              ON RIGHT(number_option,1) = T.trimmed_col
WHERE JA.status = 1 AND JA.topic = 'Current Issues'

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT JA.*
  FROM
jgl_article JA INNER JOIN
     (SELECT MAX( CAST(REPLACE(number_option, 'Issue ', '') AS UNSIGNED) ) AS MAX_number_option FROM
      jgl_article) T
              ON CAST(TRIM(JA.number_option) as UNSIGNED) = T.MAX_number_option
WHERE JA.status = 1 AND JA.topic = 'Current Issues'
```

This will work

Hope this helps..

Comment: try again  i missed a coma

Comment: return empty result set

Comment: use near 'as UNSIGNED) = T.MAX_number_option WHERE JA.status = 1 AND JA.topic = 'Current ' at line 6

Comment: YEAH.. ALIASE ERROR.. I FIXED

Comment: Unknown column 'JA.new_number_option' in 'order clause'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94054/discussion-between-subin-c-poonamgode-and-beginner).

Comment: I got an idea from query and tried this.
SELECT JA.*
  FROM
jgl_article JA INNER JOIN
     (SELECT RIGHT(number_option,1) as trimmed_col FROM jgl_article ORDER BY trimmed_col DESC LIMIT 1) T
              ON RIGHT(number_option,1) = T.trimmed_col
WHERE JA.status = 1 AND JA.topic = 'Current Issues'

it works

Comment: please try with `TRIM` rather than `RIGHT`